# Drawing line chart in chart.js with json data

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, chart.js, linechart

I'm trying to plot a line graph using a JSON response from my MongoDB. I think my code is off place I keep getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQJOk.png)

I tried this.

```
myurl = "/api/humidity"
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: myurl,
        cache: false,
        dataType : "json",
        success: function (data1) {
         //   console.log(data);
            $.each(data1.when, function(position, when) {

                if (data1.when) {

                    chartData.labels.push(data1.when);
                } else {

                    chartData.labels.push('');
                }
                chartData.datasets[0].data.push(data.message);

            });
        }
    })
})


var chartData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Humidity",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: []
        },

    ]
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line (chartData, {

});
```

Eventually I will like my code to iterate the items in my DB till its done.

this is what my JSON data look like

```
[{
    "_id": "585b544f5c86b6c8537c34d6",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:27.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54505c86b6c8537c34d7",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:28.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54515c86b6c8537c34d8",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:29.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54525c86b6c8537c34d9",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:30.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54535c86b6c8537c34da",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:31.000Z"}]
```

I will appreciate any assistance or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with chart.js version 2.2

```js
var cdata = [{
    "_id": "585b544f5c86b6c8537c34d6",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:27.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54505c86b6c8537c34d7",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:28.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54515c86b6c8537c34d8",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:29.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54525c86b6c8537c34d9",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:30.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54535c86b6c8537c34da",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 23,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:31.000Z"
}]

var labeldata = [];

var chrtdata = [];

for(var i =0; i < cdata.length; i++)
{
  labeldata.push(cdata[i].when);
  chrtdata.push(cdata[i].message)
}




var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labeldata,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Humidity',
      data: chrtdata,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
 <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. However the JSON data is dynamic. As you can see from my code it is fed from a URL.

Comment: @Ekom glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You should set up myChart like this:

```
var myChart = Chart.Line(ctx, {
    data: chartData,
    options: options
});
```

The variable 'ctx' should be passed in to the Chart function.

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart

Comment: got another error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("myChart").getContext')`

Comment: Are you calling your JavaScript inside of the <head> or at the end of <body>? It looks like the Chart.js is trying to load the canvas object before the canvas has finished loading on the page.